# "TypeError: Failed to fetch" for specific characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

> The problem only occurs if the field is called 'Authorization'

I'm trying to send a string through Swagger and I'm having problems with '/' and '='.

If I remove these chars, the request works perfectly.

What I'm trying to send is just a string header.

```
public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
{
    if (operation.Parameters == null)
        operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();

    operation.Parameters.Add(new HeaderParameter()
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        In = "header",
        Type = "string",
        Required = true
    });
}
```

I'm using Swashbuckle 2.2.0

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which [version of Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md) do you use? Can your post your Swagger YAML/JSON file? How do you enter the problematic values?

Comment: @Helen According to this page https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore, I'm using version 3.11.0. I found another characters with the same problem, like  " or (.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? How does the Network tab look like? It sounds like a CORS issue ([1](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3969#issuecomment-348651157), [2](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3403)).

Comment: @FelipeDeveza It works fine for me with the latest version of the UI, you can try it here: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index?filter=ValueProvider#/ValueProvider/ValueProvider_Put

Comment: If I send these problematic characters without being by header, the request works fine.

Comment: When I change the parameter name, solve the problem. What's going on here?

Comment: The problem only occurs if the field is called 'Authorization'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but unchecking 'Enable SSL' on Debug window solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue in my Asp.Net core 2.0 Web API. I was calling to TMDB API and trying to fetch the top rated movies with the below code.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task < IActionResult > Get() 
{
 if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
 var movies = await MovieService.GetMovies();
 return Ok(movies);
}
```

I was getting the same error as you.

[image]

Then I made the code `return Ok(movies);` to `return Ok(movies.Content);`. It did the trick.

[image]

Happy coding.